# Is it possible to use a file other than one named "pom.xml" for maven 2?

Tags: maven-2, pom.xml

I googled around a bit and couldn't find any way to do it, but was wondering if I could have a project with multiple poms for various situations, then tell maven to use 'this' one or 'that' one.

The underlying issue is we have a project that needs to be built "for production" in one manner, and "for development" in another due to vagaries in WebSphere.  I could hack up something with ant to switch in whatever pom I want by renaming it (i.e., "copy pom.xml.development pom.xml; mvn install"), but wondered if there were a more supported way.

Failing that, perhaps a way to "include" a section of pom from within a 'main' pom, so I could have my prod and dev snippets, and have maven include whichever one was appropriate based on a property or env var (or command line arg) or something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer on question body is *to use maven profiles*.

The answer on question title is *to issue*

```
$ mvn -f my_custom_pom_filename.xml
```

Answer (score 3):

Consider using Maven profiles to build artifacts for a certain environment.

See: [Introduction to build profiles](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html)

Answer (score 2):

```
mvn install -f myPOM.xml
```

OR `mvn install --file myPOM.xml`

To get the list of all command line options `mvn --help`